# Realm keychain title

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm using Realm Mobile Platform on macOS and it seems it is saved under the title "io.realm.sync.keychain". How can I change it to reflect the name of the app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently configurable. Please file an enhancement request against [Realm on GitHub](https://github.com/realm/) with some information about why you'd like to change the name of the keychain item in question.